# BatchJob and simple job showing different result

Tags: axapta, batch-processing, x++

In Ax 2009 when i write a job

```
static void (Args _args)
{
    ;
    info(Global::charMax());
}
```

Which prints '-' as expected But while i runnthe same job in a batch it returns empty space.
Could anyone assist me in this, would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Indranil Mutsuddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do this instead:

```
info(int2str(char2num(charMax(),1)));
```

you get the value 65392 = 0xFF70, which is the highest AX Unicode charater
(AX may not support the upper planes).

It may or may not display depending on you current font.
In my font it displays a square indicating it is not in the font.

See also: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Update: the `MaxChar` is first time initialized in `Application.setCharMax()`, which does a SQL reverse sort of all characters in the base plane.

Comment: why it shows different behaviour when run in simple batch(just blank) and in a job(if AX doesnt support upper planes how come it shows '-' here correctly)?

Comment: Have you tried to show the char2num value instead? It should be the same whether or not in batch. Which would indicates it is a display problem not related to AX.

Comment: You should never display maxChar() to the user - they may get confused :)

Comment: I have tried this in job info(int2str(char2num(charMax(),1))); it shows 65392, but in batch it displays 0 ...Thats where the matter is, in my case batch and job is showing different output...Yea I hope it is a display problem only.

Comment: No I wont show to anyone ;) this is my personal R&D...thanks a lot.

Comment: Ok, the value is cached, you may have do debug if the calculation is called correctly, you may start the debug in Global::charMax(), see also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc588679.aspx